# Django 1.10 Print values in same line in Templates

Tags: django

i want in same line print two value look like "1. Question ...".
but first {{ }} after set new line. look like this,

"1."

"Question ..."

```
{% for q in question %}
    <p> {{ forloop.counter }}. {{ q.question|safe }}</p>            
{% endfor %}
```

How can i print two value in same line in template ?

**I want this:**

1.Question

2.Question

...

Comment: give sample expected output?

Comment: `{{ q.question|safe }}` seems like an HTML element. so you'll have to check what is the resulting HTML for your template.

Comment: yes, it's clear what you want, but you should show us the output from your HTML source (in your browser). We don't know what `q.question` is exactly.

Comment: What is `question` in your template context? Is it a queryset? Does the model in it have a field called `question`? Does it return a string or some HTML?

Comment: @BrunoA. your comment is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: 'question' is include CKEditor content (maybe code etc.). So i use "safe" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you say that `q.question` is the content of a CKEditor. Often times, these output at least wrap the content inside a `<p>` tag. In this case, the result output generated by Django would a nested `<p>` tag inside the `<p>` from your template:

```html
<p>1. <p>Question</p></p>
```

This is invalid HTML, but the browser tries to render it as best as it can. I think you can either include the number inside the CKEditor and exclude it from your template or change your field to store a simple `CharField`, and keep your HTML unchanged.

This depends on the flexibility you want in your application.